# Plotting figures using matplotlib, over ssh using X11 and OS X

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, x11

Summary: How do I plot figures, over SSH, to a remote computer when the local computer is running OS X?

I have computer A and I am trying to use matplotlib to plot on computer B.  The problem I am having is that when I use matplotlib the plots only display on Computer A.  I VNC in and watch them pop up.  I can ssh -X/-Y into Computer A and run xcalc and it will display on computer B.  I can connect Computer B to a third computer, running Red Hat, and plots will display on Computer B. I am convinced it is not Computer B that is the problem.  [I believe my problem is the same as this problem: none of the package installers support X11 backends for matplotlib.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278186/matplotlib-backend-for-remote-plot-display-alternative-for-gtk-x11-os-x-el-cap)  I cannot comment so I'm stuck putting what I've tried in a new question.  [This is another description of the same problem with multiple solution attempts that do not work.](http://www.astrobetter.com/blog/2012/12/31/remote-display-in-python-ask-astrobetter/)

As mentioned, I have tried a lot of solutions in terms of [installing backends for matplotlib on Computer A](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#how-do-i-select-pyqt4-or-pyside).  I've tried all manor of macports and homebrew and pip combinations.  I'm pretty sure it is a bad idea to mix so many package handlers, but so many solutions seem to be "sudo ***** install package-name".

To test whether matplotlib is doing what I want I use the following python snippet:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('gtk') # gtk is an example, I change it
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot([1]*10)
```

I can't recall all the things I have tried.  Some things I have tried:

[I tried using GTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453188/matplotlib-display-plot-on-a-remote-machine) and GTKCairo, which did not solve my problem because I cannot get GTK to work.  [Homebrew GTK does not support X11 anymore anyway, so even if it did install properly I don't think it will solve my problem.](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python/issues/313)  I have not yet tried to install GTK some other way.  Would I have to install it from source?  Has anyone got this working?

The GTK error:

```
ImportError: No module named _backend_gdk
```

Backends MacOS, TkAgg, qt5agg all work but figures display on Computer A.    I had to install pyqt5.  If I am not connected via VNC, then python will thrown an error about no displays.  All three give the same error:

```
Feb 22 13:00:22  Python[57649] <Error>: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
Feb 22 13:00:22  Python[57649] <Error>: This user is not allowed access to the window system right now.
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
```

[This does not solve my problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770694/having-issues-with-matplotlib-pyplot-over-ssh)  [This doesn't either.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101063/headless-osx-server-not-allowed-access-to-the-window-system-right-now)

Details:

Computer A runs OS X 10.11
Computer B runs OS X 10.12

Edit:
I installed PyQt4 from source (along with QT) and it didn't help.  I explicitly downloaded and installed the X11 version.  I set matplotlib.use('qt4agg') and figures still appear on Computer A.  Perhaps it was my install of QT for "macosx"?  I dunno

Comment: This question has way too much going on. Is this a Python problem? An X11 problem? An installation problem?

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally hit enter and it posted.  Folks around here are quick on the draw.  The short answer is: I don't know what the problem is.  I think the problem is that most package installers for macos no longer support X11 in some relation to matplotlib.  I don't know nearly enough to concisely state the problem.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your particular problem (hence only a comment), but could you work around the issue by saving the plot to a file ([`plt.savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html?highlight=save#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig)) and transfering the image via sftp locally to view? Task could be somewhat automated if it's too cumbersome.

Comment: I considered doing that!  However, given the volume of problems I am having getting something installed I think I need figure out what detail I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This ended up leading me to the right answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453188/matplotlib-display-plot-on-a-remote-machine)  The problem was I couldn't get a backend installed that used X11.  It turns out macports has a tk version that uses x11.  I think this is actually the default setting when installing python using macports.

The steps I took to get matplotlib plotting over ssh/X11 from an OS X server (Computer A) were:

1) Uninstall the previous macports install of matplotlib and tk:

```
sudo port uninstall py27-matplotlib
sudo port uninstall py27-tkinter
sudo port uninstall tk
```

2) Re-install matplotlib to use X11

```
sudo port install tk
sudo port install py27-tkinter
sudo port install py27-matplotlib -cairo +tkinter
```

The "-cairo" may not be necessary.  tk has no flags because x11 is default.

3) Test python+matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkagg') # set the backend to tk, using agg renderer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot([1]*10)
```

This opens a figure on Computer B.

Some notes:

1) Make sure there isn't anything in your $PYTHONPATH environment variable that points to a python installation performed by another installer, like homebrew or the system python.  It might cause the wrong install of matplotlib to load.

2) [You can use a matplotlibrc configuration file to avoid having to re-specify the backend every time you open matplotlib.](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)

3) As noted in my original post, [Homebrew does not support X11 anymore for GTK.](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python/issues/313)  There is, [apparently a way to get homebrew to use tk with X11](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/MAC_Install), but I haven't figured out how to make it work yet.